# Is this subset closed under addition or multiplication and why?

Tags: linear-algebra

> V is a subset of R^3 and consists of vectors *a*{1,1,0) + *b*{0,1,1} where
> *a* and *b* are real numbers.

I am confused as to how to determine if V is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. I understand that the vectors would be closed if their sum and product are within the vector space, but the introduction of the scalars *a* and *b* has confused me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there! I think you should re-ask this question on the [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Whoops! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing `a{1,1,0}`  would be `{a, a, 0}`
So your 3D space is all vectors of the form `{a, a, 0}` and `{0, b, b}`. Is it possible to add or multiple all vectors from this set and still remain in the set?

Use an example of `a = 1` and `b = 2` and see what happens when you multiply `{a, a, 0} x {0, b, b}`.